# A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered: missing ) after argument list

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button, conga

I'm create a custom button with the help of conga and JavaScript. It usually recreates send an email feature and some additional features. But I'm getting the below error. As far as I see, I didn't miss anything in the code. Could someone help please.

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js')}
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/apex.js" )}

    IF({!ISPICKVAL( Opportunity.StageName, 'Closed Won')})
    {
    var connection = sforce.connection;
    var Opportunityx = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
    Opportunityx.Id = "{!Opportunity.Id}";
    var result = sforce.connection.update([Opportunityx]);
    window.open('https://composer.congamerge.com?SessionId={!API.Session_ID}&ServerURL={!API.Partner_Server_URL_220}&Id={!Opportunity.Id}&CETID=a2Dm00000006Zrp&CETG=Test&SC0=1&SC1=Attachments&OFN=Conga+Quote+-+{!Opportunity.Name}+-+{!Today}&DS7=2&BML=Please+Attach+PO+in+the+following+window','mywindow','width=300,height=150?')
    }
    else
    {
    alert('Please close won and enter PO number in the respective fields');
}
```

"A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered:

missing ) after argument list"

Comment: What are you trying to do with this piece of code?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 It usually recreates send an email feature and also some additional features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing called `IF` in javascript. `if` is correct. Below is the fix.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js')} 

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/apex.js" )} 


if({!ISPICKVAL( Opportunity.StageName, 'Closed Won')}) 
{ 
   var connection = sforce.connection; 
   var Opportunityx = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity"); 
   Opportunityx.Id = "{!Opportunity.Id}"; 
   var result = sforce.connection.update([Opportunityx]); 
   window.open('https://composer.congamerge.com?SessionId={!API.Session_ID}&ServerURL={!API.Partner_Server_URL_220}&Id={!Opportunity.Id}&CETID=a2Dm00000006Zrp&CETG=Test&SC0=1&SC1=Attachments&OFN=Conga+Quote+-+{!Opportunity.Name}+-+{!Today}&DS7=2&BML=Please+Attach+PO+in+the+following+window','mywindow','width=300,height=150?') 
} 
else 
{ 
   alert('Please close won and enter PO number in the respective fields'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the main issue here is the case of `if` thanks, @Ashwani.

But what if any string(sessionId, serverURL, oFN, bML) contains any special character like &' this will break this code and the fix is that just encode the strings you are passing in the URL parameters and decode on the server side where you are using these parameter values.

I have encoded 4 parameters values you can encode others if contains special characters.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/22.0/apex.js" )}     

if({!ISPICKVAL( Opportunity.StageName, 'Closed Won')}) 
    var connection = sforce.connection;
    var Opportunityx = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
    Opportunityx.Id = "{!Opportunity.Id}";
    var result = sforce.connection.update([Opportunityx]);

    /* I have encoded 4 parameters values you can encode others if contains special characters. */
    var params = {
      sessionId: encodeURIComponent('{!API.Session_ID}'),
      serverURL: encodeURIComponent('{!API.Partner_Server_URL_220}'),
      oFN: encodeURIComponent('Conga+Quote+-+{!Opportunity.Name}+-+{!Today}'),
      bML: encodeURIComponent('Please+Attach+PO+in+the+following+window')
    };

    window.open('https://composer.congamerge.com?SessionId=' + params.sessionId + '&ServerURL=' + params.serverUrl + '&Id={!Opportunity.Id}&CETID=a2Dm00000006Zrp&CETG=Test&SC0=1&SC1=Attachments&OFN=' + params.oFN + '&DS7=2&BML=' + params.oFN, 'mywindow', 'width=300,height=150');
}
```